# blocking obsolete tcp options

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, nftables

On Linux, I want to drop all packets that contain any obsolete tcp options. By obsolete options, I mean all those with a tcp option kind number above 8. How can I do this using `nftables`?

For example, if there is a way to check whether a tcp packet has an option with a given numeric kind in nftables, that would work. If nftables does not support this, can I use `tc` or another standard linux utility to do it?

Comment: AFAIK currently nftables can only check the existence of specific tcp options by explicitly stating them. To check all possible values, this would require 256-8 = 248 rules.

Comment: Also not all options above 8 are obsolete. see option 30: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8684.html

Comment: @A.B Are you saying that there is a way to do it with 248 rules? I couldn't find any way to get nftables to check for headers other than the 8 it has names for. If  there is a way to do it with a bunch of rules, could you give a snippet demonstrating this approach? Also, do you know any way to do it outside of nftables? For my use case, I don't need anything above option 8.

Comment: Posting my comment from below up here for visibility: It turns out that only recent versions of the nft command line tool allow you to specify a number instead of a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many keywords in *nftables* just represent a constant. That's the case for tcp options (**UPDATE**: but only since *nftables* 0.9.8).

Here's an excerpt for tcp options:

> [EXTENSION HEADER EXPRESSIONS](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#EXTENSION_HEADER_EXPRESSIONS)
>
> Extension header expressions refer to data from variable-sized
> protocol headers, such as IPv6 extension headers and TCP options.
>
> [...]
>
> **tcp option**
>
> {eol | noop | maxseg | window | sack-permitted | sack | sack0 | sack1
> | sack2 | sack3 | timestamp} tcp_option_field
>
> TCP Options
>
> | Keyword | Description | TCP option fields |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | eol | End of option list | kind |
> | noop | 1 Byte TCP No-op options | kind |
> | maxseg | TCP Maximum Segment Size | kind, length, size |
> | window | TCP Window Scaling | kind, length, count |
> | [...] |  |  |
> | timestamp | TCP Timestamps | kind, length, tsval, tsecr |
>
> [...]
>
> Boolean specification
>
> The following expressions support a boolean comparison:
>
> | Expression | Behaviour |
> | --- | --- |
> | fib | Check route existence. |
> | exthdr | Check IPv6 extension header existence. |
> | tcp option | Check TCP option header existence. |
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> # match if TCP timestamp option is present
> filter input tcp option timestamp exists
> ```

Here `eol` stands for 0, `nop` for 1, ... `timestamp` for 8, etc.

**UPDATE**: [since version 0.9.8](https://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-announce/2021/000249.html) it's possible to specify an arbitrary numeric value instead of a keyword:

> - Add raw tcp option match support
>
>   ... tcp option @42,16,4
>
>   where you can specify @kind,offset,length
> - Allow to check for the presence of any tcp option
>
>   ... tcp option 42 exists

So with this kind of rule:

```
nft add table t
nft add chain t c '{ type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept; }'
nft add rule t c tcp option 8 exists drop
nft add rule t c tcp option 9 exists drop
nft add rule t c tcp option 10 exists drop
[...]
nft add rule t c tcp option 254 exists drop
```

one can filter all rules with value of 8 (included to show later that 8 means `timestamp`) or above (option value is on an 8 bits field).

Known values (here only `timestamp`) are displayed with a keyword, else they stay as number:

```
# nft -a --debug=netlink list ruleset
ip t c 2
  [ exthdr load tcpopt 1b @ 8 + 0 present => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000001 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 drop ]

ip t c 3 2
  [ exthdr load tcpopt 1b @ 9 + 0 present => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000001 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 drop ]

ip t c 4 3
  [ exthdr load tcpopt 1b @ 10 + 0 present => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000001 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 drop ]

ip t c 5 4
  [ exthdr load tcpopt 1b @ 254 + 0 present => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000001 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 drop ]

table ip t { # handle 21
    chain c { # handle 1
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        tcp option timestamp exists drop # handle 2
        tcp option 9 exists drop # handle 3
        tcp option 10 exists drop # handle 4
        tcp option 254 exists drop # handle 5
    }
}
```

I didn't find a way to factorize this into sets or maps nor do comparisons with the option value, which would have simplified this, because the whole `tcp option foo` must be used in the grammar, not only `tcp option`, which as far as I understand leads to useless features like:

- Check if option timestamp which means *kind 8* has a kind value of... 8. (always true if it exists, so equivalent to `tcp option timestamp exists`):

  ```
  nft add rule t c tcp option timestamp kind == 8
  ```
- or check if option timestamp which means *kind 8* has a kind value greater than 8 (always false):

  ```
  nft add rule t c 'tcp option timestamp kind > 8'
  ```

Considering that a *tcp option* is part of a list of options, I can understand implementation isn't that easy because it has to loop through all present options to select one. Which would be chosen when two could match?

---

Note: a few options above 8 are worth keeping. For example [tcp option kind 30](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tcp-parameters/tcp-parameters.xml#tcp-parameters-1) is used for [MPTCP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8684#section-7.1) which was recently added into mainstream Linux, while tcp options kind 6 (echo) and 7 (echo reply) are obsolete.

Comment: I had tried the command you mentioned but it didn't initially work. After seeing your answer, I did some research and it seems the ability to specify a number instead of a built in name was only added in a more recent version of the nft command line utility. Upgrading allowed it run. Thanks!

Comment: So that's what actually blocked you. I updated my answer with this piece of information: requires nftables >= 0.9.8